# Libraries to mock HTTP server in scala?

Tags: scala, mocking, integration-testing

Im looking to mock out calls to a third party API from my scala microservice. Can anybody recommend a library they have tried and tested for this? I have seen a couple of older and not very active projects on github, but they do not look too promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [mock server](http://www.mock-server.com/) is appropriate for your purpose, like alternative, you can look at `[simplle framework][2]`, which is very simple in use, btw, they provide [examples of usage](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/simpleweb/svn/trunk/simple-test/src/main/java/org/simpleframework/http/validate/test/).

Answer (score 2):

I used [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) (Java)

It's very simple and yet powerful.